# Get-Recipient to Get-EXORecipient? Powershell and Exchange

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Had a quick and hopefully easy question for you guys. I've tried googling and searching but I haven't been able to find much info.

We've been asked to try and streamline and improve some scripts we have. I was trying to convert some Get-Recipient commands to the newer and quicker Get-EXORecipient module.

I'm having some issues with the below though and would appreciate any help or advice:

As part of one of my scripts, I use the below command to find a specific DDL. This works fine

```
$var1 = Get-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity "DDLName"
```

The issue I have is trying to get details from this DDL using the new module

Extract of old code which works but is quite time consuming depending on the size of the DDL

```
$var2 = Get-Recipient -RecipientPreviewFilter $var1.RecipientFilter
```

The new code I'm trying which spits out an error

```
$var2 = Get-ExoRecipient -RecipientPreviewFilter $var1.RecipientFilter
```

The error I get from the above is "Get-ExoRecipient : RecipientPreviewFilter is not a supported parameter"

I haven't been able to find out how to apply the DDL filter to this command, I tried putting the entire filter in as a string but that didn't work either. That wasn't an ideal solution as the filter may change on the exchange side.

Would appreciate any help on this one!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Get-EXORecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-exorecipient?view=exchange-ps) documentation, the `-RecipientPreviewFilter` parameter has been reserved for 'internal Microsoft use'.

[image: Recipient Preview Filter]

You should be able to use the `-Filter` parameter instead though like this:

`Get-ExoRecipient -Filter "Title -eq 'Teaching Staff'"`

However, the format of the filter returned by the dynamic distribution group may differ slightly and require some changes before it can be used with -Filter